# Blackberry message conversation list

Tags: listview, blackberry, inbox

[image]

Is it possible to implement the above default blackberry text messages conversation list view in an application.
If yes, how do I do it? I am totally blank about it, and I do not find any lead to go forward on this.
I will get the above messages from my application server.
Please help!!

Comment: Create two images like that.Add the messages on the corresponding images.Then if you get a message from server, show it in the right side of the screen, if you send a message show it on left side.

Comment: Yes Signare I did give I thought about that. But I was thinking of using the native message list view of blackberry, because if the message content is longer, then the height of that cell will change accordingly, where as the image height will be static.

Comment: create like this   final Border rightBorder = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(16, 23, 27, 16), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "bubble_right.png" ) );
          final Border leftBorder = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(16, 16, 27, 23), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "bubble_left.png" ) );

Comment: then field.setBorder(rightBorder  or leftBorder );

Comment: If not the native message view, can we use something like 9 patch image in android, for blackberry?

Comment: Hey Signare, does the "bubble_right.png" means only the image of the arrow or the complete bubble box? Cause I tried with the complete box, but if the message content increases the box image repeats itself.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I used like these images.

```
final Border rightBorder = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(16, 23, 27, 16), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "bubble_right.png" ) ); 
final Border leftBorder = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(16, 16, 27, 23), Bitmap.getBitmapResource( "bubble_left.png" ) );

addHeading(leftBorder, Field.FIELD_LEFT,0xbdbdbd, txt,time_);


 public static void addHeading(Border border, long style, int backgroundcolour, String msg ,String time_) {
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH );
    vfm.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    FieldLayout tt =  new FieldLayout(style, backgroundcolour, msg,time_);
    tt.setBorder(border);
    tt.setMargin( 5, 5, 5, 5 );
    vfm.add(tt);
    add(vfm);

}





public class FieldLayout extends VerticalFieldManager{

    Bitmap a;


     public FieldLayout(long style, final int backgroundcolour, String msg,String time_) {
  //  FieldLayout(long style,final int backgroundcolour,final String msg, final String picture) {
        super(style);


    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolour);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };



    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolour);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };

    LabelField lf = new LabelField(msg, Field.FOCUSABLE){
        private XYRect xyrect=new XYRect();
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
            Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {

                }
            });
                return true;
        }
    };
    lf.setPadding(0,0,0,3);
    vfm.add(lf);

   /* LabelField tim = new LabelField(time_, Field.FOCUSABLE){
        private XYRect xyrect=new XYRect();
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
            Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {

                }
            });
                return true;
        }
    };
    tim.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive( Font.PLAIN,5, Ui.UNITS_pt));
    tim.setPadding(3,3,0,0);
    vfm.add(tim);*/
    // set the pin point in the map 

    hfm.add(vfm);

    add(hfm);

    setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


protected void paintBackground(Graphics g){
    int oldColor = g.getColor();
    try {
        g.setColor(0xE0E0E0);

    } finally {
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code, but still the bubble repeats itself if the text content height increases. So I thought of doing something like this


LabelField lf = new LabelField("enter long text here ");
final Border chatBorder = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(16, 16, 27, 23), 
 Color.BLUEVIOLET, Border.STYLE_FILLED);
    
lf.setBorder(chatBorder);



Here I get the rounded bubble as desired, only problem is that of the arrow image, I think I have to find a way to append that arrow image to this border. Can It be done?